# Create directory (on network driver) throw an error wile runing on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I am using asp.net mvc 5 with c#. The app needs to create a folder in the server when certain action occur.

The folder has to be created in one network drive. All this works properly when the app is running in visual studio, however, doesn't work on IIS.

My guess is that the IIS does not have enough permissions, so i try to change the app pool identity, but the result wat the same.

### Edited

One thing that could not help is that the network drive was created in the software in the server (QNAP server), not in windows.

How can i make IIS behave like visual studio ?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: Is your App Pool running with a domain account that has privileges to create a folder in the network share? Once you do that it should work.

Comment: It might be worth to check with packet capture software like Wireshark, what is being sent in both cases (visual studio vs IIS)

Comment: The version of IIS is 10. It's running on windows 10. In the app pool settings we can only utilize windows account because i don't have a domain account. I will try to create a windows account with the same credentials that the ones needed to access the network and hope that will work.

Comment: No luck. My guess is that app pool user identity only works on network drivers created by windows. Since mine was created in the server software. Maybe i should change my approach. Can i create a folder in the network drivers using c#? I also need to pass in the credentials.

Comment: Mapped drives? IIS does not support mapped drives.

Comment: Although the code works fine while running in visual studio.. The final goal is to create a directory on the mapped drive. Can i do that using c# ?  To access a mapped drive i use the https protocol and i have to provide a user and password, But this credentials does not belong to a windows user, Its just a regular user of the qnap server

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a virtual directory that maps to the nas share folder. Here are a few steps.

1. In IIS on your site right click and do "Add Virtual Directory"
2. In the dialog that pops up give some alias name and in the physical path enter the location to share folder.
3. Click the connect as button. In the pop up select specific user and then enter the credentials.

Now from your code you access virtual directory.

Hope that helps.